# github who am I? (OSX)

Tags: macos, git, github

I think I'm github **USER_A**, but github thinks I'm **USER_B**. First, I check who I am:

```
$ git config --list
color.ui=auto
push.default=simple
user.name=USER_A
user.email=USER_A@gmail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/USER_A/MY_REPO.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Then, I git clone my repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USER_A/MY_REPO.git
Cloning into 'MY_REPO'...
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 6
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Then I change something, commit, and push:

```
$ git push
remote: Permission to USER_A/MY_REPO.git denied to USER_B.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/USER_A/MY_REPO.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

[This](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-other-user/) the only thing Github says about this error.

[Why does git/github think I'm pushing as **USER_B**?!](http://bit.ly/1FB5D9o)

EDIT: based on comments, I ran this test:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.131' (RSA) to the list of
known hosts.
Hi **USER_A**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
shell access.
```

I don't have a ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config file. I'm on a Mac FWIW.

Comment: It's probably not `git` that's causing this problem, but your `ssh` connection. What username are you using there?

Comment: `ssh -T git@github.com` to see which user you're hitting github with. If it says USER_B, then check your ssh config.

Comment: Thanks, I ran that (see edit at the bottom of my question), and it thinks I'm USER_A.

Comment: It’s a `https` url, SSH shouldn’t have anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you not prompted for your username / password?

Comment: No, I am not prompted for username and password. I added my ssh key to github. Actually, today I deleted and re-keygen'd my keys, deleted the old github keys and uploaded the new ones. But I get the same problem regardless.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using ssh, rather than https. Try re-cloning, but make sure you use the `ssh` url. (It should be something like: `git@github.com:username/reponame.git`).

Comment: It’s possible you have incorrect https credentials cached, see: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-mac

Comment: That wasn't the solution, but it led me to the answer, which was to search for USER_B in my OSX Keychain app. So thanks and have an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem, my Mac keychain had USER_B. I found it when I searched for "github" in the Keychain app. I've updated the question to reflect this is a Mac-specific problem/solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I was able to find out what key has been used by git using following command:

```
ssh -v -T git@github.com
```

Then, I saw another key is being used by github; So, I added my default key to SSH Agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then, problem solved :-)

Answer (score -2):

Here are a couple things I would do if your having trouble:

Run

```
Vics-iMac:ansible vic$ git config --list
```

**Explanation**:  When you configure git typically for the first time there are a lot of things that are done during the setup phase. One of them is configuring who you are, and what email address you use.  If you examine the following output from the command above.  You will see the user.name being used.

```
user.name = BlahBlah Name
user.email = blahadklhf@gmail.com
```

Comment: Downvoted: `user.name` and `user.email` listed in `git config` is just used for making a commit, not used for network authentication. The first command in original question are stating this.